# Javascript length limit of regex with given decimal conditions

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp, string-length

I could make Javacsript regex with 2 decimal points with 3 integer but the thing is I have to make it 6 digits total including the decimal "dot".

So this result should be a minimum 0 to 999.99 with the condition it's a minimum 0 to 6 digit length.

Below is my solution So far:

```
^(\d{0}(?:\d{1,3})|\d{1}\.(?:\d{1,2})|\d{2}\.(?:\d{1,2})|\d{3}\.(?:\d{1,2}))$
```

**Explanation:**
If it's 0 digits, then min 1 to 3 digits so I can make it max 999.
If it's 1 digit w/ decimal then max 2 decimal points (ex) 2.22
If it's 3 digits w/ decimal then max 2 decimal points. (ex) 3.33

This is for regex in my JSP input (which is text type) and I'm literally suffering for this problem for days.
(this regex is for versions to be specific..)

Any help or better alternative way would help me A LOT.

google search, try by myself, online course, Youtube

Answer (score 0):

If I get it well: you need to match a decimal with a length of 6 including the decimal point.

The following can do:

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

It specified a integer part up to 3 digits, then an optional decimal part.

It has some edge cases of course such as matching: `000.00` which can be cleaned up further if needed depending on your expected input.

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/LrOHvt/1